# How to query for elements which contains given string in array of strings in MongoDB (with Mongoose)

Tags: arrays, mongodb, mongoose

**This is my User schema**:

```
var UserSchema   = new Schema({
    name:String,
    groups: [String]
});
```

I want to get **array of names of all users who are in** x **group**.

**For example data set:**

```
[
    {
        "name":"a",
        "groups":[
            "1",
            "2"
        ]
    },
    {
        "name":"b",
        "groups":[
            "3x",
            "4"
        ]
    },
    {
        "name":"c",
        "groups":[
            "1",
            "4"
        ]
    },
    {
        "name":"d",
        "groups":[
            "2",
            "3"
        ]
    },
    {
        "name":"e",
        "groups":[
        ]
    }
]
```

**I need results:**

```
for group 1:
["a","c"]

for group 2:
["a","d"]

for group 3:
["b","d"]

for group 4:
["c"]

for group 5:
[]
```

**Is it possible to write query like this? How to do it?**

Comment: you should also add what you've tried (code-wise)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is quiet simple, Just requires an aggregate operation with two stages.

- [*$unwind*](https://docs.mongodb.org/v3.0/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/) by the `groups` field.
- [*$group*](https://docs.mongodb.org/v3.0/reference/operator/aggregation/group/) by the `groups` field

Code:

```
db.t.aggregate([
{$unwind:"$groups"},
{$group:{"_id":"$groups","names":{$addToSet:"$name"}}}
])
```

Sample Result:

```
{ "_id" : "3x", "names" : [ "b" ] }
{ "_id" : "4", "names" : [ "c", "b" ] }
{ "_id" : "2", "names" : [ "d", "a" ] }
{ "_id" : "3", "names" : [ "d" ] }
{ "_id" : "1", "names" : [ "c", "a" ] }
```